# Find the leaf count for each parent ul in a nested ul structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a html structure that looks like the following html, but is of arbitrary depth. (i.e. it could go many levels deeper). Because it is of arbitray depth, I would prefer a solution that doesn't require adding any extra markup to the html (e.g. classes)

```
<ul><!-- Leaf Count 3 -->
  <li>branch 1
    <ul><!-- Leaf Count 2 -->
      <li>leaf 1</li>
      <li>leaf 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>leaf 3</li>
</ul>
```

How can I count all the leaves that are a child of each ul? So in this example the outer most ul would have 3 leaves and the nested one two leaves. This seems like a recursion issue, but I can't think through it.

Comment: Do all your li, either contains the word leaf or branch?

Comment: `So in this example the outer most ul would have 3 leaves and the nested one two leaves.` not 3 only 2

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen no they don't contain that text, I just put it in there to make it more clear

Comment: @Hopeless Then why would the first ul not contain 4?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I think the top most `li` is a "branch point", not leaf.

Comment: How the first ul have 3 leaves? It's 2 i think

Comment: @MayurPatel I'm counting any ```li``` that doesn't have children as a leaf

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen since it doesn't have any children, it is a leaf even though it is on the same level as a branch.

Comment: Weird how people try to close these types of questions asking "what did you try", whereas some questions end up in Hot Network Questions queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think accepted answer is not more efficient. There is even simpler way of doing this.

We can use jquery simple selectee `li:not(:has(*))`. This will find all li element that doesn't have children(leaf node).

Use `$("#dvMain").find('ul').each` which will find all `ul` element and then loop through it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dvMain").find('ul').each(function(item) {
        console.log($(this).find('li:not(:has(*))').length);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dvMain">
<ul><!-- Leaf Count 4 -->
  <li>branch 1
    <ul><!-- Leaf Count 2 -->
      <li>leaf 1</li>
      <li>leaf 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>branch 1
    <ul><!-- Leaf Count 1 -->
      <li>leaf 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>leaf 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I like how compact this is! Good going. I like the lack of mark up to.

Answer (score 1):

If it is preferred not to change HTML, jQuery's `filter` can be used:

```js
function filterLeaf(ele) {
  if ($(ele).children().length === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var nouter = $('#outer').find('li').filter(function() {
  return filterLeaf(this);
}).length;
var ninner = $('#inner').find('li').filter(function() {
  return filterLeaf(this);
}).length;
console.log(nouter);
console.log(ninner);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="outer"><!-- Leaf Count 3 -->
  <li>branch 1
    <ul id="inner"><!-- Leaf Count 2 -->
      <li>leaf 1</li>
      <li>leaf 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>leaf 3</li>
</ul>
```

Or, when generate the HTML, add class name such as "leaf" to the leaf element, and then using jQuery's `.find`:

```js
var nouter = $('#outer').find('.leaf').length;
var ninner = $('#inner').find('.leaf').length;
console.log(nouter);
console.log(ninner);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="outer"><!-- Leaf Count 3 -->
  <li>branch 1
    <ul id="inner"><!-- Leaf Count 2 -->
      <li class="leaf">leaf 1</li>
      <li class="leaf">leaf 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="leaf">leaf 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm looking for solutions that don't add extra markup to html. I clarified in my answer. Adding a class of leaf is the first thing that popped into my head.

Comment: @Hopeless I've edited my answer. If you don't want to change html, jQuery's `filter` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($("ul.outer>li").length)
console.log($("ul.inner>li").length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='outer'><!-- Leaf Count 3 -->
  <li>branch 1
    <ul class="inner"><!-- Leaf Count 2 -->
      <li>leaf 1</li>
      <li>leaf 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>leaf 3</li>
</ul>
```

1. To count direct child use `>`

Comment: the code you posted shows an ouput of 2 for the first one. Also, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require altering the html with classes, because I don't know how deep the nested structure will go. I will update the question to clarify that.

Comment: @Hopeless the first ul has only 2 li

Comment: yep, but I want it to count all ```li``` that are children that don't have any children themselves

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TreeWalker api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker), and sum all the children of a `<ul>` that don't have children of their own.

```js
const treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.body,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT
);

const result = [];

while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
  const node = treeWalker.currentNode;

  if (node.nodeName === 'UL') {
    result.push([...node.querySelectorAll('li')].filter((node) => !node.children.length).length);
  }
};

console.log(result);
```

```html
<ul>
  <!-- Leaf Count 7 -->
  <li>branch 1
    <ul>
      <!-- Leaf Count 6 -->
      <li>leaf 1</li>
      <li>leaf 2</li>
      <li>branch 2
        <ul>
          <!-- Leaf Count 2 -->
          <li>leaf 1</li>
          <li>leaf 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>branch 3
        <ul>
          <!-- Leaf Count 2 -->
          <li>leaf 1</li>
          <li>leaf 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>leaf 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use even this

```js
$('ul').each(function(a){
count = 0;
$(this).find('li').each(function(){
if($(this).children().length ==0){
count++;
}

});
console.log(' ul level '+a+' count : '+count);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul><!-- Leaf Count 3 -->
  <li>branch 1
    <ul><!-- Leaf Count 2 -->
      <li>leaf 1</li>
      <li>leaf 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>leaf 3</li>
</ul>
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4j2o1qbs/1/)**